# How to connect to a MySQL server running on a Virtual Machine

Tags: mysql, virtual-machine

I have a MySQL Server 5.5.32 running on Ubuntu 12.04. Ubuntu is being run on VM. Host platform is Windows 7. **How can I connect with the Ubuntu's MySQL from Windows?**

I have done the following so far:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Running a `show grant for root;` displays this:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@%                                           |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But when I try to connect to this server from SQLYog running on Windows, I get an error `Error 2003 Cannot connect to mysql server on '192.168.xxx.xxx'`.

The IP being feed to SQLYog, I got it from `ifconfig`. Supplied the inet addr.

```
inet addr:192.168.226.xxx  Bcast:192.168.226.yyy
```

Is the address being used is incorrect or are these grant issues? Please advice.

Comment: Can you ping your VM from Host OS?

Comment: @fliespl oops... nope.. I can't. Any suggestions on how I can make it happen?

Comment: Please try my answer first (change bind-address of mysql).

Comment: @flispl changed the bind-address to 0.0.0.0 but still fails to connect

Comment: Are you sure that host and VM are visible to each other and that your are using correct port? Have you checked if your firewall is not blocking port 3306?

Answer (score 20):

You problem is that (probably) your mysql is bind to `127.0.0.1` instead of `0.0.0.0`.

You should change bind in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` to `0.0.0.0`

`bind-address            = 0.0.0.0`

And then restart mysql of course.

Comment: Could anyone please explain why this solves the problem?

Comment: Binding to 127.0.0.1 allows connections only from localhost, while 0.0.0.0 allows from "any host".

Comment: I myself had to search for it in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/` with version 5.6.31 on Ubuntu.

Comment: you can also just comment out the bind-address line

Comment: Pretty much this is bad advice, as it now allows any ip to connect to your mysql instance/ Instead of locking it does to the ip you know of.

Comment: I am able to connect using this method. Thanks!

Comment: For my mariadb friends: sudo vi /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf

Answer (score 4):

In newer versions of MySQL, instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on localhost
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1

So you need to add your machine IP to here or simply comment it out if you are not worry about security concerns.

Answer (score 1):

The error message `Error No. 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (or some other host)`

simply means that connection is not possible for one of the following (or similar) reasons:

- There is no MySQL server running at the specified host
- Connection to the MySQL server is not allowed using TCP-IP. Check the 'skip-networking' setting in the MySQL configuration file (my.ini on Windows, my.cnf on Unix/Linux). It shall be commented out like '#skip-networking'. If it is not commented out, then do it and restart the MySQL server for the change to take effect. SQLyog needs to connect using TCP-IP.
- Some networking issue prevents connection. It could be a network malconfiguration or a firewall issue. We have experienced sometimes that some firewalls is blocking TCP-IP connections even if it claims to be disabled. Most often it will help to uninstall and reinstall the firewall.
- When trying to connect to a MySQL server at an ISP this error message often indicates that direct connection to MySQL has been blocked. You must then use HTTP-tunneling or SSH-tunneling to connect.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with the **Network Adapter settings** in your VM settings

Do like this in your VM settings.

**VM Settings -> Network Adapter Settings -> Select Bridged**

The VM will connect to the physical network when the network connection is on **bridged mode**.

Try to ping the VM host in your windows machine after changing the network connection to **bridged**.

If the VM is pinging in your windows machine  then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Error No. 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.x.x'

simply means that connection is not possible for one of the following (or similar) reasons:

- There is no MySQL server running at the specified host
- Connection to the MySQL server is not allowed using TCP-IP. Check the 'skip-networking' setting in the MySQL configuration file (my.ini on Windows, my.cnf on Unix/Linux). It shall be commented out like '#skip-networking'. If it is not commented out, then do it and restart the MySQL server for the change to take effect. SQLyog needs to connect using TCP-IP.
- Make sure that you are able to connect to MySQL port using telnet

  C:\telnet hostname/IP_address port